# How to get current itemView row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 ViewHolders: for default and expanded (with some more text).

When user clicks on row, it should switch its viewholder to expanded one. In my code below, when I click on itemView, every itemView change it view, not only target row. How to handle this? Thanks

```
private boolean isClicked;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewHoldertype = getItemViewType(position);

    Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

    switch (viewHoldertype) {
        case TYPE_ARTICLE:

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                toggleItem();
            });
            break;
        case TYPE_EXPANDED_ARTICLE:
            final ExpandedViewHolder expandedItemHolder = (ExpandedViewHolder) holder;
            expandedItemHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
            expandedItemHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            expandedItemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                switch();
            });
            break;
    }
}

void switch() {
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.image)
    ImageView image;
    @Bind(R.id.title)
    TextView title;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setTag(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

class ExpandedViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.description)
    TextView description;

    public ExpandedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you store the position of your view when setting the OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder or you obtain the current position via RecyclerView.getChildPosition(view) in your onClick call. You can then change your items state (expand it) and force the Recyclerview to redraw the selected item.

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
    ...
}
```